How to update a row value in a column with the first value in a separate column based on a repeating sequence
I want to track a repeating sequence in a data frame column ("SeqCol"), and note whenever the sequence gets set back to 0 (or at least near zero). Whenever the sequence resets, I want to make make note in a separate column ("Counter"), but also take the first value from my main column ("MainCol") for a final column ("NewCol")
I start with a data frame like this:
MainCol<-seq(1:20)
SeqCol<-rep(1:5,4)
SeqCol<-jitter(SeqCol)
DF<-data.frame(MainCol, SeqCol)


#Need Unique Counter whenever SeqCol starts over
DF<-DF %>% mutate(Counter = cumsum(SeqCol < lag(SeqCol, default = Inf)))

DF$NewCol<-NA
NewDF<-data.frame()

This next part works, but is incredibly inefficient and slow when applied to a large data frame.
Uni<-unique(DF$Counter)
for(i in seq(1,length(Uni))){

  MyChunk<-DF[DF$Counter==i,]
  MyNewName<-MyChunk[1,"MainCol"]
  
  MyChunk$NewCol<-MyNewName
  
  NewDF<-rbind(NewDF,MyChunk)
  
}

I would like to replicate the results from the above for loop, but with a more efficient method.

As noted below, I'm using dplyr::lag here

Presumably you are using dplyr::lag, in which case a dplyr approach could be:
DF |>
  mutate(Counter = cumsum(SeqCol < lag(SeqCol, default = Inf)),
         NewCol = row_number()) |>
  mutate(NewCol = first(NewCol), .by = Counter)

Should be much faster. I presume it is the creation of a fresh MyChunk and applying rbind at every row that is slowing you down.
